# Производительный обмен сообщениями на QUdpSocket - возможно ли?

Tags: c++, qt, udp

Пытаюсь написать быструю кросплатформенную систему обмена сообщениями с гарантированной доставкой на Qt, через `QUdpSocket`. Конечная цель - шина, промежуточная - издатель-подписчик, начальная - "точка в точку". UDP - чтобы не тратить время на connect'ы.

Структура такая: издатель ведёт список подписчиков, по каждому храня номер последнего отправленного сообщения из кольцевой очереди. "Долбится" с этим сообщением, пока подписчик не подтвердит, что успешно его принял, после чего издатель переходит к следующему. Поскольку предполагается небольшое количество подписчиков, на каждого можно выделить отдельный поток и работать блокирующими функциями. Поэтому издателей сделал перегрузкой `QThread`, всю работу перенеся в `run()`. Подписчики ждут сигнала `readyRead()`, соответственно, нуждаются в `EventLoop`. Поэтому подписчика унаследовал от `QObject` и перенёс в новый `QThread` через `moveToThread()`. Вот основные куски кода:

```cpp
void GQ::Subscriber::read()
{
    while(socket_.hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        arr_.resize(socket_.pendingDatagramSize());
        socket_.readDatagram(arr_.data(),arr_.size(),&addr_,&senderPort_);
        QDataStream is(arr_);
        is>>number_;
        //qDebug()<<"<<"<<arr_.size()<<number_;
        reply_.setRawData((char*)&number_,sizeof(number_));
        socket_.writeDatagram(reply_,addr_,senderPort_);
    }
}

void    GQ::Publisher::run()
{
...
while(validAddress)
{
    if (updateSubscriber_)
    {
        QTime   time1;
        time1.start();
        // Займёмся гарантированной доставкой
        auto item=buffer_->itemByID(firstToSend);
        // Нет такого элемента
        while (!item.isNull())
        {
            firstToSend=item->ID;
            arr=GQ::toByteArray(*item.data());

            uint timeout=minTimeout;
            quint64 startTime=QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
            socket.write(arr);
            bool receivedOk=false;
            do
            {
                // Если за таймаут ничего не пришло - посылаем снова
                while (!socket.waitForReadyRead(timeout))
                {
                    qDebug()<<"Timeout, writing again";
                    socket.write(arr);
                    quint64 elapsed=QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()-startTime;
                    qDebug()<<"Elapsed: "<<elapsed<<"timeout: "<<timeout;
                    if ((elapsed>(timeout*toutMultiplier))&&(timeout<maxTimeout))
                    {
                        timeout*=toutMultiplier;
                        qDebug()<<"Increasing timeout";
                    }
                }
                QByteArray received=socket.readAll();
                quint64 * number=(quint64 *)received.data();
//              qDebug()<<"Sent: "<<firstToSend<<"; received: "<<*number;
                receivedOk=(*number==firstToSend);
            } while (!receivedOk);
//          qDebug()<<"elapsed: "<<time.elapsed()<<"="
//                  <<QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()-startTime;
            item=buffer_->itemByID(++firstToSend);
        }
        updateSubscriber_=false;//*/
        quint64 elapsed1=time1.elapsed();
        if (elapsed1>10)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Total elapsed:"<<elapsed1<<","<<100000*1000/elapsed1<<"mps";
        }
    } else msleep(100);
```

**Результаты**. Я проверил производительность (W10, MinGW, i7, памяти полно, Gigabit Ethernet, пересылаю очередь из 100000 пакетов по 1 кб+заголовок), получил такие результаты:

- 1 издатель+1 подписчик на одном и том же узле - порядка 14.5К сообщений в секунду.
- 5-10 издателей+1 подписчик на одном и том же узле - порядка 40-45К сообщений в секунду.
- 1 издатель+1 подписчик на разных узлах - порядка 900 сообщений в секунду, при подключении через Wi-Fi - вообще около 450.

Попробовал подписчика тоже унаследовать от `QThread`, поместив в `run()` такой код:

```
forever
{
    while(socket_.hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        QByteArray  arr_.resize(socket_.pendingDatagramSize());
        socket_.readDatagram(arr_.data(),arr_.size(),&addr_,&senderPort_);
        QDataStream is(arr_);
        is>>number_;
//      qDebug()<<"<<"<<arr_.size()<<number_;
        reply_.setRawData((char*)&number_,sizeof(number_));
        socket_.writeDatagram(reply_,addr_,senderPort_);
    }
    msleep(10);
}
```

и получил падение до 450 сообщений в секунду даже на одном узле.

Теперь собственно вопросы:

1. Почему такая фиговая производительность получается? Под QNX 4 через QNET у нас 40000 сообщений в секунду пролетало ещё лет 20 назад, на тогдашней технике и через 100 Mbit. Неужели Qt - такая "толстая" обёртка, или я что-то принципиально не так делаю?
2. Почему перенос в `QThread::run()` так подорвал производительность? Я-то рассчитывал обойти сигналы/слоты Qt'шные, а получилось ещё медленнее.
3. Куда копать для более скоростного обмена? Я успел слегка "пощупать" ZeroMQ и nanomsg. Первую просто задолбался ставить под MinGW, она зависит от других библиотек. А nanomsg собралась относительно небольшой кровью, но для отправки подтверждения приёма надо выковыривать параметры отправителя (или он тоже должен порт открывать, что нежелательно), и стандартные команды отправки/приёма не годятся, надо специализированные использовать - в результате код получается страшнее, чем через UDP. Поможет ли мне `boost::asio`, или ещё что? Или просто я UDP неправильно готовлю?

**Update1:** Пересобрал и проверил производительность под `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` на той же машине:

- 1 издатель + 1 подписчик на одном узле - 32-33К сообщений в секунду.
- 10 издателей + 1 подписчик на одном узле - 150-160К сообщений в секунду.
- 1 издатель + 1 подписчик на разных узлах через Wi-Fi - 330 сообщений в секунду.

Так что для обмена сообщениями внутри узла под Linux скорости для моих задач хватит, а между узлами всё ещё полная беда. На днях попробуем собрать проект у коллеги под VS, чтобы понять, тормозит ли [внутриузловой обмен] виндовая реализация Socket'ов или MinGW.

**Update2:** Собрать под VS в ближайшее время не получится. Мы в силу ряда причин привязаны к `Qt4.7`, готовые сборки под VS есть только для `VS2008`, а расширения `C++11`, которые я использую, в VS есть только начиная с `VS2010`. Можно, конечно, и `Qt4.7` под что-то свежее пересобрать, но пока ни мне, ни коллегам не до того.

**Update3:** Прикрутил кэш - добился от однопоточного обмена такой же производительности, как от многопоточного. Сделал версию с `boost::asio` вместо `Qt`, на одном узле даже однопоточный обмен вырос до 35К. Но в любом случае через сеть производительность получается не выше 1-1.3К через Gigabit Ethernet, 0.3-0.5К через Wi-Fi 802.11n. То есть используется где-то 10-15% пропускной способности канала. "Будем искать".

Comment: "Куда копать"  - это не конкретный вопрос. Это не сайт, где пишут ТЗ или делают постановку задачи.

Comment: Это сайт, где люди с разным уровнем знаний обмениваются опытом. Я в высоконагруженные системы только влез, ещё не знаю, что в этой области есть. А люди с опытом в данной области знают, могут ответить что-то типа "я на asio прогонял 20К сообщений, больше не пролезало", или "asio тоже тяжёлая библиотека, пощупай то-то". Для этого и спросил, в общем-то.

Comment: Вы заблуждаетесь. Это не сайт, где люди обмениваются опытом. Это сайт вопросов и ответов.  Более того, совершенно не понятно, зачем вы привели свой код? Есть отдельный раздел, где делается код-ревью.

Comment: 1. Ответ на вопрос - это передача опыта от отвечающего к спрашивающему. Так что противопоставление, IMHO, не требуется. 2. Я мог допустить какие-то ошибки в коде, и просто из вопроса, без кода, было бы непонятно, есть они или нет. А так можно "пальцем" ткнуть и сказать: "Вот здесь неправильно". По крайней мере, в англоязычном сегменте stackoverflow вопросов типа "делаю так, что неправильно?" полно. 3. Можно ссылочку на раздел с code review? Буду благодарен.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Я бы сам с удовольствием почитал обстоятельные ответы на него. Первое, что приходит в голову, низкая скорость следствие синхроного подтверждения.

Comment: @BMP Как говорится, в чужой монастырь со своим уставом не ходят.Ответ на вопрос не есть передача опыта. Это всего лишь ответ, то есть чья-то точка зрения, которая к тому же может быть полностью некорректной и более того, даже противоречить собственному опыту.:) Я считаю, что ваш вопрос должен быть закрыт. Никто не будет для вас заниматься написанием ТЗ, то есть "куда копать дальше".:)

Comment: При чём здесь вообще написание ТЗ или постановка задачи? Под "куда копать дальше" подразумевалось исключительно "кто знает работающие библиотеки для решения задачи?" или "ты неправильно делаешь то-то". Если уж это не передача опыта, то я Вашу терминологию совсем не понимаю.

Comment: @avp - да, синхронность скорее всего является одним из "тормозящих" факторов, и увеличение пропускной способности при увеличении количества издателей об этом явно говорит. Пока издатель был один, подписчик простаивал в то время, пока издатель разбирал ответ - а при увеличении количества издателей подписчику всегда есть чем заняться. Я подумаю, можно ли в нашем случае перейти на асинхронный обмен, хотя навскидку такой возможности не вижу.

Comment: @avp, спасибо за идею. Я прикручу к издателю небольшой "кэш", чтобы он посылал не по одному сообщению, а сразу пачку, и ждал подтверждения получения пакетов. Так я с одного издателя смогу получить производительность порядка 40К пакетов. А заодно и посмотрю, какая производительность будет через Ethernet.

Comment: Не уверен, что асинхронность реализуется запросто (в винде, тем более на qt я вообще не пишу). Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону [reliable udp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RUDP)

Comment: А "пачки" -- это здравая идея, в чем-то похожая на TCP (или с учетом границ пакетов SCTP?)

Comment: А библиотеку UDT не рассматривали? http://udt.sourceforge.net/software.html

Comment: @user3195373, спасибо, посмотрю. Правда, меня смущают два момента - то, что она позиционируется как протокол для передачи больших объёмов ("transfer bulk data"), и что последний выпуск - в 2011 году.

Answer (score 1):

При вашей схеме все обработчики событий QEvent связанные с GQ::Publisher будут выполнятся в контексте потока в котором вы создали GQ::Publisher то есть, видимо, в главном потоке. Следовательно все они будут выполнятся синхронно. Вы скажете что вам они и не нужны, что вы специально от них уходили. А я вам отвечу, а кто вам сказал что события не используются внутри QUdpSocket к примеру?

Вообще вы не совсем правильно используете QThread. Он не то чтобы поток сам по себе который исполняется асинхронно с другими, он скорее апартамент в понятиях COM. QThread нужен для того чтобы пробрасывать QEvent'ы так чтобы они обрабатывались синхронно но в контексте этого потока.

Поэтому правильнее было бы GQ::Publisher отнаследовать от QObject, работу с сокетами и таймерами построить на сигналах/слотах. Ну и не забыть посадить паблишер в отдельный апартамент. То есть сделать GQ::Publisher так же как вы сделали подписчиков.

Напомню что такое партаменты COM. В COM'е есть три потоковые модели: однопоточная, мультипоточная и апартаментная. Каждый объект COM обязан сообщать о модели которую он поддерживает. Потоковая модель это стандартизированный контракт который обязуются выполнять клиент и сервер. В однопоточной модели все вызовы к серверу синхронные потому что должны выполнятся из одного потока, в мультипоточной вызовы могут выполнятся полностью асинхронно из разных потоков, в апартаментной модели вызовы выполняются синхронно но из разных потоков. На самом деле там посложней все, но принцип думаю понятен.

Comment: В главном потоке я использую только один метод GQ::Publisher - метод "обновись", который взводит бит updateSubscriber_. QUdpSocket я создаю внутри метода run, то есть уже внутри потока Publisher'а. Поскольку с COM я не работал, понятие "апартамент" мне, увы, незнакомо. Но наследовать Publisher'а от QObject и переносить через moveToThread() я пробовал, производительность была такая же. Этот момент меня больше всего удивил - почему для Subscriber'а способ реализации так сильно сказался на производительности.

Comment: Буду очень признателен, если "на пальцах" разъясните понятие "апартамент" - COM большая, глубоко в неё лезть только для данной задачи мне, думаю, не нужно, а вот лучше понять QThread всегда полезно.

Comment: @BMP дополнил ответ

Comment: Да, интересно. Действительно, QThread похож на апартамент: сигналы из другого потока Qt превращает в event'ы, они направляются целевому потоку - а вызвавшая функция потока-источника висит на emit'е, и по event'у об окончании обработки продолжает выполнение. Но ведь внутри одного потока посылка сигнала превращается в простой вызов слота, поэтому, создавая QUdpSocket внутри run() я и рассчитывал на более быструю работу за счёт экономии времени на межпоточном взаимодействии.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено! Такая низкая скорость получается тогда, когда одна сторона `bind`'ит порт, а другая подключается через `connect`. Сообщения в сторону узла, не открывшего порт, идут почему-то очень медленно. Когда же я сделал `bind` на обеих сторонах и перешёл на простые `readDatagram`/`writeDatagram`, удалось добиться скорости порядка 70-80К сообщений на одном узле и 30-35К между узлами. То есть примерно 30% от ширины канала (`Gigabit Ethernet`), что для режима "запрос - ответ" я считаю приемлемым результатом. К сожалению, необходимость открывать порт на обеих сторонах усложняет архитектуру, ну да что-нибудь придумаем.